# Drupal AMP theme add jQuery library

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, amp-html

How can I include jQuery library, Bootstrap.js in Drupal 7 [AMP](https://www.drupal.org/project/amp) Theme? I searched, but couldn't find any example.

Answer (score 1):

Simple way is download [JQuery update](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_update) module.

Add bootstrap.js in theme settings file(themename.info):

```
;scripts[] = js/Bootstrap.js.js
```